# User's profile information not updating

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I writed code for users to update their information(username and image) using Firebase, but it is not working. The progress bar shows, and then the toast message saying it is successful, but nothing on the profile page and in the Realtime Database changes. I don't know where the problem could be, there are not any visible errors, but if someone here could tell, I would be glad to knwo. Here is the code for my Settings Activity:

```
class AccountSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    private var checker = ""
    private var myUrl = ""
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private var storageProfilePicRef: StorageReference? = null
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    companion object {
        val pickImage = 100
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_settings)

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        storageProfilePicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Profile Pictures")

        val logoutbtn = findViewById<Button>(logout_btn)

        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()

            val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, SignInActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        val changeImage = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.change_image_text_btn)
        val saveInfBtn = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.save_infor_profile_btn)
        changeImage.setOnClickListener{
            pickImageGallery()
        }
        saveInfBtn.setOnClickListener {

                uploadImageAndUpdateInfo()
        }
        userInfo()
    }
    private fun pickImageGallery() {
        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(gallery, pickImage)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        var profilepic = findViewById<ImageView>(profile_image_view_profile_frag)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {
            imageUri = data?.data
            profilepic.setImageURI(imageUri)

        }
    }

    private fun updateUserInfoOnly()
    {                val usernameSettings = findViewById<EditText>(username_profile_frag)

        when {
            usernameSettings.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please write user name first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else -> {
                val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                userMap["username"] = usernameSettings.text.toString().toLowerCase()

                usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Account Information has been updated successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()

                val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun userInfo()
    {
        val usernameSettings = findViewById<EditText>(username_profile_frag)
        val imageSettings = findViewById<ImageView>(profile_image_view_profile_frag)

        val usersRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                .child(firebaseUser.uid)

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if (p0.exists()) {
                    val user = p0.getValue<User>(User::class.java)

                    Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(imageSettings)
                    usernameSettings.setText(user!!.getUsername())

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    private fun uploadImageAndUpdateInfo()
    {            val usernameSettings = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_profile_frag)

        when
        {
            imageUri == null -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            usernameSettings.text.toString() == "" -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please write user name first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else -> {
                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                progressDialog.setTitle("Account Settings")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, we are updating your profile...")
                progressDialog.show()

                val fileRef = storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser!!.uid + ".jpg")

                var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
                uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>{ task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        task.exception?.let {
                            throw it
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl
                }).addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<Uri> {task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val downloadUrl = task.result
                        myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
                        val usernameSettings = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_profile_frag)

                        val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        userMap["username"] = usernameSettings.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        userMap["image"] = myUrl

                        ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Account Information has been updated successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                } )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, p0.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is caused due to invoking `userInfo()` method in `onCreateView` before returning `view`, so when you are trying to access `profile_fragment_username`  or `pro_image_profile_frag` using `view?.findViewById` it would return `null` as `view` not yet set at this point.

To fix this either call `userInfo()` inside `onViewCreated()` or pass `view` to `userInfo(view)` and access it from fun parameter!